# how to remove the duplicate rows when we used group by method?

Tags: sql-server

i used the group by the method for distinct the two column values. But still i got the duplicate values in the column rows.

```
    SELECT MRD_NO,RESOURCE_NAME,
Diagnosis = 
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + 
     (case when Diagnosis is null and OTHER_DIAGONSIS is not null then OTHER_DIAGONSIS else Diagnosis end)
           FROM EMR_master b 
           WHERE b.MRD_NO = a.MRD_NO 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') 
FROM EMR_master a 
where
a.TREATMENT_CODE in ('CC','PO','SRE','REG') 
group by MRD_NO,RESOURCE_NAME
order by RESOURCE_NAME,MRD_NO
```

my output contains the duplicate values in the MRD_NO column, tell me how to remove the duplicate values.

my output

```
MRD_NO |  RESOURCE_NAME  | Diagnosis
123    |  james          | retina 
126    |  peter          | throat pain 
129    |  Murugan        | fever
129    |  william        | fever
130    |  william        | retina
```

i need like this output

```
MRD_NO |  RESOURCE_NAME  | Diagnosis
    123    |  james          | retina 
    126    |  peter          | throat pain 
    129    |  Murugan        | fever        
    130    |  william        | retina
```

**note:** i got duplicates MRD_NO 129 with two resource name(Murugan,william),
so i need to eliminate the william and get unique MRD_NO

Comment: may I have table script with sample records?

Comment: You use two columns in the group by clause but you wait for no duplicates in one of them. Why do?

Comment: you can remove the group by and use distinct

Comment: @DenisRubashkinI need to count the MRD_NO based on the resource_name that's why am asking

Comment: @Scidhar, you wrote in your question that you had duplicate values in the MRD_NO column though didn't mention that RESOURCE_NAME is duplicated as well.

Comment: Use `Distinct` as @PSK suggested or use any aggregation function for your third column or add the column to the group by clause.

Comment: Can you provide some sample raw data?

Comment: This shouldn't generate duplicate values of MRD_NO, RESOURCE_NAME there's something else here. Check if both 'Murugan' are really the same value, maybe there are some hidden characters.

Comment: @ EzLo you are right i got different resource_name with same MRD_NO,

Answer (score 0):

Try to choose a column in `DISTINCT` operator:

```
SELECT MRD_NO,RESOURCE_NAME,
Diagnosis = 
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT b.MRD_NO + ', ' + 
     (case 
          when Diagnosis is null and OTHER_DIAGONSIS is not null 
              then OTHER_DIAGONSIS else Diagnosis end)
      FROM EMR_master b 
      WHERE b.MRD_NO = a.MRD_NO 
      GROUP BY b.MRD_NO, b.RESOURCE_NAME
      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') 
FROM EMR_master a 
where
a.TREATMENT_CODE in ('CC','PO','SRE','REG') 
group by MRD_NO,RESOURCE_NAME
order by RESOURCE_NAME,MRD_NO
```

E.g.:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE 
(
EmpID int, 
EmpName varchar(50),    
DateOfJoin datetime,
DateOfLeaving DATETIME,
StatusName VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @table
(
    EmpID,
    EmpName,
    DateOfJoin,
    DateOfLeaving,
    StatusName
)
VALUES
 (1, 'XYZ',      '2015-10-01',    '2017-09-26', 'De-ACTIVE')
,(2, 'ABC',      '2018-01-01',    NULL, 'ACTIVE')                      
,(3, 'XYZ',      '2018-10-15',    NULL, 'ACTIVE')
```

and query:

```
SELECT 
hey = STUFF((
        SELECT 
        DISTINCT t.EmpName + ', '
        FROM @table t
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')        
FROM @table t
```

OUTPUT:

```
hey
C, XYZ, 
C, XYZ, 
C, XYZ,
```

**UPDATE:**

If you would like just to remove duplicates, then you should just use `GROUP BY` to field where you want to get rid of duplicates.

```
SELECT
  MRD_NO
, RESOURCE_NAME 
, Diagnosis
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY MRD_NO
, RESOURCE_NAME 
, Diagnosis
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to much work around and getting desired output you can do with temptable

```
       SELECT MRD_NO,RESOURCE_NAME,     
            STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + 
             (case when Diagnosis is null and OTHER_DIAGONSIS is not null then OTHER_DIAGONSIS else Diagnosis end) as 'Diagnosis'

into #tmpEmrDetail
               FROM EMR_master b 
               WHERE b.MRD_NO = a.MRD_NO 
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') 
    FROM EMR_master a 
    where
    a.TREATMENT_CODE in ('CC','PO','SRE','REG') 
    group by MRD_NO,RESOURCE_NAME
    order by RESOURCE_NAME,MRD_NO

select distinct * from #tmpEmrDetail

drop table #tmpEmrDetail
```

or

```
; WITH ctetbl AS
     (
     SELECT MRD_NO,RESOURCE_NAME,
Diagnosis = 
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + 
     (case when Diagnosis is null and OTHER_DIAGONSIS is not null then OTHER_DIAGONSIS else Diagnosis end)
           FROM EMR_master b 
           WHERE b.MRD_NO = a.MRD_NO 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') 
FROM EMR_master a 
where
a.TREATMENT_CODE in ('CC','PO','SRE','REG') 
group by MRD_NO,RESOURCE_NAME


     )
     SELECT *
     FROM ctetbl order by RESOURCE_NAME,MRD_NO
```